# Grammatical function of 'however'

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions, grammatical-roles

In the below sentence, what is the grammatical function (adverb, preposition, etc.) of 'however', and why? Most dictionaries say 'however' is an adverb, but I cannot understand why this is so, esp. in the sense of the below sentence.

> However you look at it, he is wrong.

Comment: Dictionaries are not the right place to look for parts of speech. Especially if they say it's an adverb; that's a wastebasket category, because there are dozens of different kinds, all with different grammar and uses. Not helpful to know. f you really want to know how _however_ is used in this sentence, look at sentences like it.

Comment: See ['However' as a conjunction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/492352/however-as-a-conjunction), where @BillJ says 'Here, "however" is a relative adverb in a fused relative construction.'